# how bank maintain session by allowing single login at a time

Tags: java, session

I am using struts2,jsp,hibernate to develop my application . Can any one tell me the best way to maintain session for allowing single login per user. do i have to store all user login session id in context or any other way to that? please explain about this

Comment: Check the title, do you mean `maintain` session ?

Comment: yes,user should login once and if user login using other browser first login session should be invalidated.

Comment: What's the point, seriously? Everybody has phones, computers, tablets. Why would you annoy people by disconnecting them when they connect using another of their browsers?

Comment: Its online banking process, so i have to track session and the process should be same like banks maintain the session, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Did you check `OpenSessionInViewFilter`?

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this done in one project, using a Servlet Filter and the database.  As part of your login process you create an entry in a db table.  Call it a "LoginSession" table or whatever you want.  Also as part of creating the record in the table, invalidate any previous entries in that table for the same user.  Associate the users current session id cookie with that entry.  Then in  your Servlet Filter, which you'd have filter every request, check the database, to see if this request has a still valid entry in your "LoginSession" table.  If so let the request continue.  If not, redirect them to the home/login/logout page of your choice.